# A to html converted notebook is not showing the data in all plots

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook

"When I create a Jupyter Notebook with multiple graphs, they are visible. However, when I save this notebook as HTML, the graphs are displayed, but the data from the first graphs disappears again. I found the following message via 'inspect' and 'console': 24 WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost. Node cannot be found on the current page."
How can i solve this ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import plotly.express as px

# Create DF
start_date = datetime(2018, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime(2022, 12, 31)
num_days = (end_date - start_date).days + 1
num_cols = 100
data = np.random.rand(num_days, num_cols)
dates = [start_date + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(num_days)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[f"Column_{i+1}" for i in range(num_cols)])
df['Date'] = dates

x = 10
while x < len(df.columns):
    columns_to_plot = df.columns[x-10:x].tolist()
    fig = px.line(df, x=df['Date'], y=columns_to_plot)
    fig.show()
    x += 10
```

Comment: One alternative that may not spring to mind besides limiting the contexts as the warning hints at would be to save the plots as images and then use code to load them back into the notebook output.

Answer (score 0):

try different browser, like edge or google chrome or firefox

maybe saving as *.ipynb format file is better. no need to care about html